# What is "signature recovery"?

Tags: lightning-network, public-key, signature, invoices

[Bolt #11](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/11-payment-encoding.md) defines a "tagged field," n, which identifies the payee by a public key, but it isn't required.  It also requires a signature which can be verified only if the public key is known.  When tagged field n is not included, something called "signature recovery" is required.  How does that work?

I ask because I was thinking that if I get two invoices, I should be able to determine if they indicate the same payee.  I thought tagged field 'n' would be great for this, but it might not be supplied.  So how can I compare the two invoices to see if they came from the same node?  If signature recovery is built in, I guess that means I can get the public key even if tagged field 'n' is missing.  But how would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

It is as you suspect: You can [recover the public key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Public_key_recovery) knowing only the signature and the message. The recovery id byte in the signature is not strictly necessary as there's a brute force option, but it is included for efficiency.

There's an implementation of public key recovery in bitcoin core's [secp256k1](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1/blob/master/src/modules/recovery/main_impl.h) library.