# How can i get the payee public key from the payment request

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, invoices

I'm trying to get the payees public key (destination node) from the payment request. You can [see an example here](https://lightningdecoder.com/lnbc4300n1p320r89pp59wlvxy3dky9t69q5jx5yupe9mrsxt8yp5dgwe3dnqn9fnjmz0zfsdp8xgcryv3dxqmj6vfn2scnjw33x5argwfwxv6nwkscqzpgxqyz5vqrzjq0nfr7qlprzkl2rke380tj0gkunm66pv7dtqt0396jrq02qz2fs9xzeqeyqqyucqqqqqqqqqqqqzwrcq9gsp5hc5nutnjdvalz4x3a8972s3rj4smh5c9hq857w2ksx357x34xx2q9qyyssq49mawcvxvr0faestf7f5xy8rnfpn9ls3uwjlkpsudk8lh9w9d2p5nal7plje0dfq54ww66pr6hgwucakp78k3ntcmxtsm9frpewm4ycq7sltp5).

In the source code for (https://lightningdecoder.com/) it seems like they get it from a tag or tag 19 (?) but I can't find this information in the decoded payment requests i get from LND:

https://github.com/andrerfneves/lightning-decoder/blob/0fd4bdcd9ec01e8bacd0a475543186ad2de3fe27/src/lib/bolt11.js#L386-L394

**Does any one know how to get this?** Preferably using Go and the invoice returned by LND

[image]

Comment: It's not quoite a duplicate question but I think the answer you seek for was given in the past to a similar question: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/96205

Comment: Thank you Rene, I think I can solve my question based on the answer you posted above. I’ll update this post once I have an example of the solution for future reference here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I ended up using:

```
// var invoice *lnrpc.Invoice

inva, err := zpay32.Decode(invoice.PaymentRequest, &chaincfg.MainNetParams)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

fmt.Sprintf("%x", inva.Destination.SerializeCompressed())
```

Alternatively, I think you can replace the `fmt.Sprintf` with `hex.EncodeToString`

```
hex.EncodeToString(inva.Destination.SerializeCompressed())
```